# Spring MVC login functionality not working. Always redirecting to login page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I was trying Spring MVC login functionality in one of my sample application. But, it always redirects to login page.

Below is my code:
**application-security.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true"  use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/login" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <form-login login-page="/admin/login" default-target-url="/admin/student" authentication-failure-url="/admin/login/failed" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="roul@gmail.com" password="passw0rd" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

**AuthenticationController.java**

```html
package com.spring.schoolmangement;

import java.util.Locale;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

/**
 * Handles requests for for user authentication.
 */
@Controller
public class AuthenticationController {

    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/admin/login", "/admin/login/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String displayLogin(Locale locale, Model model) {
        return "login-form";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/admin/login/failed", "/admin/login/failed/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String validateLogin(Locale locale, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("error", true);
        return "login-form";
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/application-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

And Finally here is my login.jsp page:

```html
<jsp:directive.page import="java.util.Calendar" />
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <div class="account-wall">
            <img class="profile-img" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-b0-k99FZlyE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/eu7opA4byxI/photo.jpg?sz=120" alt="User" />
            <form class="form-signin" name="f" action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check'/>" method="POST">

                <%-- <c:if test="${not empty param.login_error}"> --%>
                    <font color="red"> ${sessionScope["SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"].message}</font>
                <%-- </c:if> --%>

                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="j_username" required autofocus />
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name='j_password' required />
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
                <label class="checkbox pull-left">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me">Remember me
                </label>
                <a href="#" class="pull-right need-help">Need help? </a><span class="clearfix"></span>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Think you need to add the CSRF token as hidden field to your form. CSRF is enabled by default.

Comment: @fateddy - not true.  CSRF protection is enabled by default [only with Java based configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf).  There are plans to enable it by default for XML based configuration as well, but for now it needs to be enabled by adding the `<csrf/> tag to an `<http/>` tag.

Comment: @manish - ok wasn't aware of that (used JavaConfig on a recent project).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out the mistake I was doing. Following is the change I made in login view.

**Previously:**

```html
<form class="form-signin" name="f" action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check'/>" method="POST">
```

**Now:**

```html
<form class="form-signin" name="f" action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check'/>" method="POST">
```

That means I was missing a "/" in the post action URL. Very silly mistake.

I also modified my application-security.xml for complete login functionality as below:

```html
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />
 <http pattern="/admin/login" security="none" />
 <http pattern="/admin/login/failed" security="none" />
 <http pattern="/admin/login/invalidsession" security="none" />

 <http auto-config="true"  use-expressions="false">
  <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
  <form-login login-page="/admin/login" default-target-url="/admin/student" authentication-failure-url="/admin/login/failed" />
  <session-management invalid-session-url="/admin/login/invalidsession" />
  <logout logout-success-url="/admin/login" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
 </http>

 <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
  <authentication-provider>
   <user-service>
    <user name="roul" password="roul" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
   </user-service>
  </authentication-provider>
 </authentication-manager>
```